# Why doesn't my chart in excel 2013 auto update whenever i add in additional data?

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I'm still new to VBA thus I don't have much knowledge in VBA. Regarding this matter I've searched it online and tried most of the given solutions on Stack Overflow and still couldn't make it work. The only way that work is by doing it manually daily which I hope not to. Everyday I will add data into the worksheet to generate a comparison chart for me. I've tried using various  method :
 - chart.refresh
 - do events
 - refreshall

Sadly, none of them work for my workbook. Other than that, I have 2 chart that needs to be updated in a worksheet and I have 3 worksheets. So I will be literally updating 6 charts at once. Is there a way to make it work without doing it manually ?

[image: The highlighted area in the first picture is for the chart on the left]

[image: The highlighted area in the second picture is for the chart on the right]

This is the code that I'm working on right now and updating the chart is the last part already.

```
Sub trial()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim fn As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
Dim Ret

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Lkl Files (*.lkl), *.lkl")

    If Ret <> False Then
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "SPC_PLTB_450B_12092107_25°C_CW"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = "."
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        End With
    End If


    Sheets(2).Activate

    'this is for the date (loop)

    Dim FirstCell As String
        Dim i As Integer
            FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Range("$A$9:$P$417").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        "1"
    Range("F31:F401").Select
    Selection.Copy



    Sheets(2).Activate


    'this is for the raw data

            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

   Sheets(3).Activate
    FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate

    Range("D31:D401").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy


    Sheets(3).Activate
            FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        Sheets(4).Activate
    FirstCell = "C19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop
            ActiveCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ws.Activate

    Range("G31:G401").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy



    Sheets(4).Activate
    FirstCell = "D19"
            Range(FirstCell).Select
            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
            Loop


    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

Worksheets(5).Delete


End Sub
```